# Merging DataFrames with Different Columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` as shown by the first two dataframes in the image below. I want to combine them to get `df_desired` as shown by the final dataframe in the image. My current attempts result in the third dataframe in the image; as you can see it is ignoring the fact that it has already seen a row with name `a`

My code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b'], 'data1':[3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','c'], 'data2':[1,5]})

def collect_results(target_list, df_list):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name','data1','data2'])
    for i in range(2):
        target = target_list[i]
        df_target = df_list[i]
        smiles = list(df_target['name'])
        pxc50 = list(df_target[target])
        target_col_names = ['name', target]
        df_target_info = pd.DataFrame(columns=target_col_names)
        df_target_info['name'] = smiles
        df_target_info[target] = pxc50
        try:
            df = pd.merge(df,df_target_info, how="outer", on=["name",target])
        except IndexError:
            df = df.reindex_axis(df.columns.union(df_target_info.columns), axis=1)
    return df
```

How can I get the desired behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can merge on `name` with outer join using [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df_desired = df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='outer')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_desired)


  name  data1  data2
0    a    3.0    1.0
1    b    4.0    NaN
2    c    NaN    5.0
```